# Need to click twice on jQuery UI button after enabling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got this simple button made using jquery UI with a very simple click functionality:

```
    $('#bewerkopslaan').button({
        icons: {
            primary: 'ui-icon-disk'
        },
        disabled: true
    }).click(function() {
        alert('test');
            });
```

At some point I enable the button like this:

```
    $('#bewerkopslaan').button("option", "disabled", false);
```

Then I can click the button but... nothing happens. Then I click it again and it works.
So I always have to click it twice.

Comment: Are you enabling the button in a click handler on the button? Mind posting a http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com demo?

Comment: which navigator are you using?

Comment: I'm using chromium. Strange enough, the code works great in Firefox. (albeit a little slower ;))

Answer (score 2):

I wrote exactly what  you mentioned but, the code works great. [Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/xNpgu/).

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided will enable the button correctly from my testing, however, the button having a disabled state does not disable the click event you've added. If you want the button to be truly disabled you need to bind the event only when you enable the button and unbind the click when you disable the button.

example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/WmAQJ/1/

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#bewerkopslaan').button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-disk'
    },
    disabled: true
  });

  $('#enabler').click(function() {
      $('#bewerkopslaan').button("option", "disabled", false).bind("click", function() {
        alert('test');
      })
  });

  $('#disabler').click(function() {
      $('#bewerkopslaan').button("option", "disabled", true).unbind("click")
  });
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="enabler">click me to enable button</div>
  <span id="bewerkopslaan">button</span>
  <div id="disabler">click me to disable button</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The click event wasn't triggered when the button was disabled. However, I still implemented your method. It works in Firefox, but not in Chromium.

Comment: What version are you running? This works fine for me in Chrome 10.0.648.133 Have you customized your Chromium at all before building it?